# I need your help on bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
eval export ${1:+-n} -- "${1}=\${config_${2}_{3}:-\${4}}";;
```

What does this line do? I am new to shell. Could you interpret it for me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a substitute for Google or documentation.

Comment: You can ask it in unix Q&A

Answer (score 2):

**eval** - construct command by concatenating arguments

**export** - Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.

**${parameter:+word}** - If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

**${1}, ${2}, ${3}, %{4}** - are arguments passed to the function/script

Now just glue it all together, determine what are arguments and you have a command that is now well known and easier to undesrstand.